# Using Data to drive Player (Name, Shirt#) and Position( e.g. Goalkeeper, Center Forward) etc. variables to set up Soccer Lineup

Tags: macros, datatool

I have a soccer field template and then I have a hardcoded listing of parameters I use to set up their position on the soccer field.
I am using 3 parameters :: Jersey Number, Player Name, (First Coordinate, Second Coordinate).
But it is hard to make this dynamic and change field posisions.
I want to use two datatables: Players {Jersey#, Name}  and Positions {GoalKeeper, (Coordinates)}.
How can I do that ?

My code:

```
\SoccerStrikers{Jersey Number:1}{Player1}{(.5,4.5)}
\SoccerStrikers{35}{Player2}{(3.2,8)}
\SoccerStrikers{9}{Player3}{(1.8,6)}
\SoccerStrikers{7}{Player4}{(1.8,3)}
\SoccerStrikers{10}{Player5}{(3.2,1)}
\SoccerStrikers{91}{Player6}{(3.7,4.5)}
\SoccerStrikers{5}{Player7}{(6.5,7.5)}
\SoccerStrikers{12}{Player8}{(5.5,5.5)}
\SoccerStrikers{6}{Player9}{(5.5,3.5)}
\SoccerStrikers{15}{Player10}{(6.5,1.5)}
\SoccerStrikers{22}{Player11}{(8.2,4.5)}
```

Comment: I think you need to give more information, it is hard to guess from the code shown what it does and what do you want to change. Why is it hard to change the coordinates what syntax do you want to define?

Comment: This is what database programs are good at.  If you can export a (comma delimited) text file, you can print it with LaTeX.

Comment: And what do you want to do with the data once you got it? Draw them into your output? Do you need to store the data to be able to re-access it later or do you just need it once?

Comment: I am trying to visualize the lineup during the start and through a few substitutions.  So initially : let us say I need to be able to say: Player 1, Center Forward.  This in turn will translate to the Player's Jersey # & Name along appearing at the center forward position.    ( The Center Forward Position will translate to the two coordinates...) <BR>  Then after the first substitution say Player1 moves to  Left Back position and so on for each of the players... trying to simplify the hardcoded portions of the visualization

Answer (score 2):

Without really knowing what you plan to do with this, the following uses `expl3` and property lists to store the information. Every access is fully expandable, storing of course not.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_saupa_players_names_prop
\prop_new:N \g_saupa_players_numbers_prop
\prop_new:N \g_saupa_players_positions_prop
\prop_new:N \g_saupa_players_coords_prop
\NewDocumentCommand \newplayer { m m m m m }
  { \saupa_new_player:nnnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \saupa_new_player:nnnnn #1#2#3#4#5
  {
    \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_saupa_players_names_prop {#1}
      { \msg_error:nnn { saupa } { player-already-known } {#1} }
      {
        \prop_gput:Nnn \g_saupa_players_names_prop     {#1} {#2}
        \prop_gput:Nnn \g_saupa_players_numbers_prop   {#1} {#3}
        \prop_gput:Nnn \g_saupa_players_positions_prop {#1} {#4}
        \prop_gput:Nnn \g_saupa_players_coords_prop    {#1} {#5}
      }
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \playername { m }
  { \prop_item:Nn \g_saupa_players_names_prop {#1} }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \playernumber { m }
  { \prop_item:Nn \g_saupa_players_numbers_prop {#1} }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \playerposition { m }
  { \prop_item:Nn \g_saupa_players_positions_prop {#1} }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \playercoordinates { m }
  { \prop_item:Nn \g_saupa_players_coords_prop {#1} }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \drawplayer { O{gray} m }
  {
    \draw[fill=#1]
      (\playercoordinates{#2})
      circle[radius=1] node[below]{\playername{#2}}
      ;
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newplayer{me}{Skillmon}{43}{Answerer}{5,7}
\newplayer{saupa}{Saupa}{1}{Asker}{-40,15}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
The player \playername{me} has the number \playernumber{me} plays on
position \playerposition{me} and should be placed at
(\playercoordinates{me}).

The player \playername{saupa} has the number \playernumber{saupa} plays on
position \playerposition{saupa} and should be placed at
(\playercoordinates{saupa}).

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
  \draw
    (-52.5,-34.75) coordinate(bl) rectangle (52.5,34.75) coordinate(tr)
    (0,0) coordinate(c) circle[radius=9.15]
    (c|-bl) -- (c|-tr)
    ;
  \draw
    (c-|bl) +(0,-9.16) rectangle +(5.5, 9.16)
            +(0,-20.16) rectangle +(16.5, 20.16)
    ;
  \fill
    (c) circle[radius=.24]
    (c-|bl) +(11,0) coordinate(pl) circle[radius=.24]
    ;
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (c-|bl) ++(16.5,9.15)rectangle++(9.15,-18.3);
    \draw (pl) circle[radius=9.15];
  \end{scope}
  \draw
    (c-|tr) +(0,-9.16) rectangle +(-5.5, 9.16)
            +(0,-20.16) rectangle +(-16.5, 20.16)
    ;
  \fill
    (c) circle[radius=.24]
    (c-|tr) +(-11,0) coordinate(pr) circle[radius=.24]
    ;
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (c-|tr) ++(-16.5,9.15)rectangle++(-9.15,-18.3);
    \draw (pr) circle[radius=9.15];
  \end{scope}
  \drawplayer{me}
  \drawplayer{saupa}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will try this out.  I have a similar soccer field map and in addition to the name, the players jersey# appears. Much like what is shown say at the start of an EPL game